# Adding JPanel to JLayeredPane causes paint() method to not get called

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, paint, repaint

To provide some background info that might help, I am creating the game pong and I decided to add an escape/pause menu (when you press escape on the keyboard a menu pops up with some settings), I looked around and found that the best way to do this is to use JLayeredPane and add another JPanel on top. However, when I added my 'painter' class to the JLayeredPane, the paint(Graphics g) method stopped getting called (it worked fine when I just added it to the JFrame).

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    public static Painter painter;

    public Game() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLayeredPane lp = getLayeredPane();

        painter = new Painter();

        add(lp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game frame = new Game();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        painter.repaint();
    }

}
```

And here is my Painter class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Working");
        super.paint(g);
    }

}
```

Instead of `add(lp);`, I originally tried `lp.add(painter);` in which case the paint method never got called. By doing `add(lp)` I get an IllegalArgumentException for adding container's parent to itself.

Comment: You should `add(lp)`. For more help post [mcve].  I would suggest reading [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first post here. I did try `add(lp)` but it did not work, the error message was "adding container's parent to itself". I'll start reading that, thanks. If you are able to figure anything out, however, please let me know! @c0der

Comment: Please update the posted code with the change you did. Adding `JLayeredPane` to the `JFrame` should not cause this error.  **"If you are able to figure anything out"** - I can try, after you post [mcve]

Comment: @c0der this is as minimal I can get while still replicating the issue, anything less and the code would not be complete

Comment: Sorry. Ignore my comment. I was referring to [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is mcve of using LayeredPane :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    public Game() {
        setSize(250, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLayeredPane lp = getLayeredPane();
        //assign layout manager. otherwise you need to set content
        //bounds (not recommended)
        lp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Painter painter = new Painter();
        lp.add(painter,1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game frame = new Game();
        frame.setVisible(true);;
    }
}

class Painter extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //do not override paint
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Working",50,50);
    }
}
```